# Error TF218027 when creating a Team Project in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, permissions, reporting-services

Consider the scenario of a user creating a new Team Project. The user is a developer who wants to create and manage their Team Project.

- Why can't this user create a new Team Project, including the Reporting Services components?
- What can be done to resolve this error?

The exception is

> TF218027: the following reporting folder could not be created on the server running SQL Reporting Services.

SQL Reporting services is running under an Active Directory service account created expressly for this purpose.

[image]

The developer attempting this action is a member of a TFS group with the following permissions.

[image]

Comment: I'm having this issue also, I granted Content Manager in Reporting Services and made sure it was running using NETWORK SERVICE.  Is there anything else that I could be missing?  Am I overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The <strike>workaround</strike> way that I implemented was to ensure the developer was in a group that had 'Content Manager' permissions in the SQL Reporting Services.

I simply added the appropriate AD group in the textbox, and the operation worked perfectly.
First I visited the SSRS page at http://myServer/TFS/Reports/MyCollection

[image]

Enter the "New Role Assignment" screen.

[image]

Comment: That is not a work around! If you read the documentation you will see that this is specified in there. When an admin grants a user permission to create new team projects they need to also add them to the Create Site permission in Sharepoint and Content Manager in Reporting servies.

Answer (score 3):

I actually [blogged](http://www.smartchitecture.com/blog/post/TFS-error-TF218027-The-following-reporting-folder-could-not-be-created-on-the-server.aspx) about this not too long ago.  You usually see this error if Reporting Services gets set up with something other than the `NETWORK SERVICE` account.

FTA:

> I was playing around with my test
>   instance of Team Foundation Server
>   today, trying to create a new project,
>   when I got error TF218027 when it
>   tried to create the Reporting Services
>   folder for the project.  The strange
>   thing was, this was not my first
>   project created on this server.
>
> I searched the Internet for anything
>   similar, and found a post that said
>   Reporting Services should be run with
>   the NETWORK SERVICE account.  Since
>   this was a hastily put together
>   server, I was running it with the
>   Administrator account, so I tried
>   switching it over.
>
> No dice.  I got the same TF218027
>   error, but this time it was due to it
>   not being able to decrypt the
>   symmetric keys.  Apparently, it's a
>   bad thing to change the account on the
>   Reporting Services service.
>
> I hastily changed the account back to
>   Administrator and resarted the
>   service.  Interestingly enough, this
>   seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: thank you for this answer. Indeed we're using an AD service account for the Reporting Services. I saw your blogpost before creating this question, and it did give me something to consider. I'm hoping to find an answer that doesn't require that solution....yet. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I just run throught the same issue.  I granted the user rights in SharePoint, TFS, and Report Server.  And still I was getting the same error message.  Then I realized something.  I added that user to the Report Server's local administrator's group. It worked! Hopefully this help you out.