# TFS create project error

Tags: tfs

[image: display this error when i create new project]

My tfs 2012 is installed on a remote server and i connect to that using vs2013 when i create new project the above error is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, If you are granted permission to create new team projects then your user-id need to be added to the Create Site permission in Sharepoint and Content Manager in Reporting services.

That is, you need to have permissions on your reporting services site to create new folders.

See:

[How to: Set Administrator Permissions for Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253091(VS.80).aspx)

[Error TF218027 when creating a Team Project in TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241420/error-tf218027-when-creating-a-team-project-in-tfs-2010)