# Issue while creating TFS Team Project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I’m doing a VSS to TFS upgrade for my team. We have configured the TFS server, now I’m trying to create a Team project on the server from my local VS2013 and I get an error as in the attached picture.

I have Farm administrator rights on SharePoint site, Full admin access to the Collection where I’m trying to create the Team project, Content Manager Rights on the Reports Folder.

I have cleared the TFS cache on my local as well.

Can you please help me out if I’m missing anything?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configured TFS to have Reports, it tries to create a folder in Reporting Services and populate with some pre-canned reports.

The error says that it is not able to find the machine with Reporting Services. Review the configuration at the console, if you can ping the machine, if port 80 (or another if you changed default) is reachable.

Comment: The user account you used needs to be one of the Content Manager group in SSRS, please have a double check on it. See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241420/error-tf218027-when-creating-a-team-project-in-tfs-2010 .

Comment: Thanks Giulio, that was the issue. It was not resolving to the hostname of the server. Had to change the link to use the server IP and it did the magic