# Cant create new team project in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I have an old setup with a tfs2010 and sql2008 and the current Collection is holding 3 team Projects. Now i want to create a new team project but for some reason i cant. it seems that it has something to do with the SQL Reporting that dosent excists. i get an error TF218027.

Ive been going through the setup and im wondering a bit

1. What exactly does the TFS use the reportServer for (MSDN dosent seem to want to tell me)
2. is there any way to create a Team project without the reporting
3. Will it damage my excisting data if i create and connect to a new sql reportServer

Hope someone will take the time to give an answer
thanks.

I have already tried the different approtaches discussed on different threads and im primarily looking for information on the 3 questions written above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error TF218027 when creating a Team Project in TFS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241420/error-tf218027-when-creating-a-team-project-in-tfs-2010)

Comment: Well its similar and ive already read it but im still unsure how to resolve the issues. i would really hate to break the tfs server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the people that actually read the question the answer is.

1. Keeps track of agile work progress
2. yes and its actually easy. go to the reporting service and stop it and then tell TFS not to report under reporting
3. Since it was never running the answer here is No

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps below:

1. In browser go to: `http://application-tier/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx`
2. Press **Folder settings** button in the toolbar
3. Press **New Role Assignment** button in the toolbar
4. Specify user name in **Group or user name** field, check **Content Manager** role and press OK.

Comment: Thats already tried but it seems that the reportServer is non excisting. there for my questions. so im more looking on information to the 3 questions i wrote above